# How to make a generic type T Array for a generic SortedLinkedList?

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, sortedlist, toarray

I have implemented a SortedLinkedList with generic types but one of the assignments is to make a `toArray`method that takes a `T[]` array and fills it with the elements of the Linked List. For this, I figured I'd make a `get()`method that returns the value of the Node at that point and fill the array with those values. Unfortunately, I'm hitting IndexOutofBoundsExceptions and I'm not sure where my issue is exactly. If anyone could help, it'd be much appreciated!

My `get`method:

```
public T get(int i) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        Node<T> n = head; 
        if (i < 0)
             throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        if(i==0)
             return head.element;
        while(n != null && i > 0){
            n = n.next; 
            i--;
        }
         if (n == null)
             throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        return n.element;
    }
```

And my `toArray` method:

```
public T[] toArray(T[] array){
        int len = this.size();
        //T[] copy = (T[]) new Comparable[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            array[i] = this.get(i);
        }
        return array; 
    }
```

The compiler complains about an OutOfBoundsException at `array[i] = this.get(i)`and I really don't get why. Any help would be much appreciated, and I'm happy to provide more of the SortedList code if needed. Thanks!

Comment: You wrote several lines of code that throw IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions in `get`.  It looks like you're hitting one.

Comment: It should be easy to find the problem debuging. What line is throwing the exception? You are not checking the array size. Could it be that the array is smaller than the list and when you try to assign something it fails?

Comment: in a `while` loop you have termination condition `n != null` As a result you'll get `OutOfBoundsException ` when loop is finished.

Comment: Easier would be to create a single loop with a variable to keep track of an array index.

Comment: @alex even removing the `if(n == null)`exception, the code gives me the same mistake. And I don't quite get what you mean with a single loop to keep track of the index? You mean to put the whole `get` method in a while loop?

Comment: sure, since you removed if `(n == null)`  exception thrown when java tried to to execute `n.element` Can you put error stacktrace to the question description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I mean by single loop was this pseudocode

```
T array
index = 0
Node node -> point to linked list head  
Iterate until node is null:
  array[index] = node.element
  node -> point to next element
  index++
```

Comment: ok with your pseudocode, I made the loop as you suggested. But the OutOfBoundsException still pops up if I ask for `list.get(0)`in my main method. It says `unreported exception IndexOutOfBoundsException; must be caught or declared to be thrown` - so the issue is also in my `get`method.

Comment: okay, thanks for the help, I got the correct answer, it was with the help of your pseudocode so thanks!!